# Connecting react native app and mongodb via nodejs and express js

Tags: node.js

when connecting react native app and nodejs i get error in front end as  ERROR  Error fetching workouts: Network request failed.
how to fix this error

to solve this error

```
const [workouts,setWorkouts]=useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8001/api/workouts/');
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network request failed');
            }
            const json = await response.json();
            setWorkouts(json);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching workouts:', error.message);
            // Handle the error appropriately (e.g., display an error message to the user)
        }
    };
    fetchWorkouts();
}, []); this is the code
```

Comment: Is your backend running on same port as you mentioned ( 8081 ), and is it running properly?